# How to Close the goroutine which waiting on I/O

Tags: concurrency, go, goroutine

I have created two go routines **sender** and **receiver**, sender will continuous get the data from the user(keyboard) and write to stream, receiver will independently get the value from stream print it to the screen. Both are concurrent using go routine

At some point of time receiver failed and close the connection as well as exit the receiver go routine, but sender go routine which waiting for user input(i/o operation) will not be closed. How to exit all the go routines in this scenario?

Below is the piece of sample code for this scenario.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var stop bool = false

func sender() {
    str := ""
    for !stop {
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)
        fmt.Println("Entered :", str)
    }   
    fmt.Println("Closing sender goroutine")
}

func receiver() {
    i := 0
    for !stop {
        i++
        if i > 5 { 
            stop = true
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }   
    fmt.Println("Closing receiver goroutine")
}

func main() {
    go sender()
    go receiver()

    /* Wait for goroutines to finish */
    for !stop {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
    }   
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    panic("Display stack")
}
```

Above code sender will wait for user input after 5 loop receiver will exit the receiver go routine. *`I expect when receiver close, go routine which waiting on i/o has to be closed.`*

Kindly help me on this question.

Comment: Side note: it is unsafe to read and write the same variable (`stop`) concurrently. Don't *ever* do this. This is a classic data race and has [completely undefined behaviour](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong). Go's [race detector](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector) can point these out to you.

Comment: You aren't actually sending anything in this example. However, if you're just wanting raw data (strings, bytes) then perhaps an `io.Pipe` may be convenient with both sides doing a `defer myside.Close()` (where `myside` is either the read or write side of the pipe as appropriate). In the general case you'd use a channel to send the data and the writer can close it to signal it's done; but the reader shouldn't/can't close; that usually means you'd need a separate channel or other synchronization mechanism to signal the writer to exit.

Answer (score 3):

As Dave C & JimB say, use channels to coordinate goroutines. Here's an example that may help.

Exit after receiving 5 messages from the user:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var pipe = make(chan string) //shares text entered by user
var stop = make(chan bool)   //shares stop signal

func listen() {
    for {
        var input string
        fmt.Scan(&input)
        pipe <- input
    }
}

func write() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        var output string
        output = <-pipe
        fmt.Println("Received", output)
    }

    stop <- true
}

func main() {
    go listen()
    go write()

    <-stop
}
```

Comment: In your example code listen() go routine will not exited after 5 write at by write() go routine because it will stay in the for loop itself, it probably a leak. only main() and write() will exited properly. use panic statement at end of the main and check the stack trace.  This expecting solution for this scenario

Comment: I agree with JimB; easiest to leave the goroutine running if the scan can't be avoided. But perhaps this [pipe technique](https://github.com/mindreframer/golang-devops-stuff/blob/master/src/github.com/mitchellh/packer/stdin.go) or [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/4ZrDw__VkyI) could help?

Answer (score 1):

To start, your code has a race around the `stop` variable. When there's a data race, there's no guarantee your program will behave as defined. Use channels to synchronize goroutines. This however isn't why you program continues.

Your code is blocking on `fmt.Scanf`, and doesn't get to check the `stop` condition. Since a Read on Stdin can't be interrupted (which is happening inside `fmt.Scanf`), you need to check for the stop condition *before* calling `Scanf`again. If there's no more input, but you have a pending Read on Stdin, the easiest way to handle it is to just let leave that goroutine running. There are some rather complex ways to break out of this using something known as the "self-pipe" trick, but it's generally not worth the effort, as goroutines are small and don't take many resources.

```
for {
    fmt.Scanf("%s", &str)
    fmt.Println("Entered :", str)
    // use a channel or context to detect when to exit
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return
    default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In your solution after  fmt.Scanf executed then only  execution will come to select and for return, my question when there is no input for fmt.Scanf then how i can close the go routine.

Comment: @sujin: as explained in the answer, you can't directly interrupt the Read of stdin (this isn't a Go issue, in POSIX you can't interrupt a `read` from another thread). You could use the `select` syscall to only read if data is available, and return from the goroutine asynchronously, but why bother? If you know what the end of the input is supposed to be, return then. If the input stream ends, you get `EOF`. If you don't know what the end of the input stream is, then you either have an error, or you need to leave the Read open anyway.