# How to terminate a console input request when a new input is requested

Tags: go

I need to terminate an existing console input request when a new one is requested. The following code is an attempt to close an existing request using a channel but it does not seem to terminate the input request.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go Confirm("you are a programmer, aint you?")
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    Confirm("do you love go?")
}

var cancelChannel chan struct{}

func Confirm(s string) bool {
    //check if channel type holds a value then close the channel to remove previous confirmation input
    if cancelChannel != nil {
        fmt.Println("channel to be closed")
        close(cancelChannel)
    }
    cancelChannel = make(chan struct{})
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%s [y/n]: ", s)

        response, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        response = strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(response))

        if response == "y" || response == "yes" {
            return true
        } else if response == "n" || response == "no" {
            return false
        }

        if _, ok := <-cancelChannel; !ok {
            fmt.Println("channel closed")
            return false
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You can't wrap the same stream multiple times with separate buffered readers, since they _buffer_ data. You can't interrupt a read on stdin, so you just let the goroutine continue until the fd is closed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548428/how-to-close-the-goroutine-which-waiting-on-i-o/30549695).

Answer (score 1):

As @JimB mentioned in comment you can't interrupt read on stdin although there is kinda shady trick how you can achieve it. It's possible to duplicate `os.Stdin` file descriptor using `syscall` *(not recommended)* and open it as non blocking file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "io/fs"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func setNonblock(f *os.File) error {
    c, err := f.SyscallConn()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var err2 error
    err = c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
        err2 = syscall.SetNonblock(int(fd), true)
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return err2
}

func nonBlockingFile(f *os.File) (*os.File, error) {
    if err := setNonblock(f); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fd, err := syscall.Dup(int(f.Fd()))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    f2 := os.NewFile(uintptr(fd), f.Name())
    return f2, nil
}

func read(ctx context.Context, f *os.File) (io.Reader, error) {
    r, err := nonBlockingFile(f)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    go func() {
        defer r.Close()
        <-ctx.Done()
    }()
    buff := bytes.NewBuffer([]byte{})
    for {
        _, err := io.Copy(buff, r)
        if err != nil {
            if errors.Is(err, fs.ErrClosed) {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    return buff, nil
}

func main() {
    ctx1, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        cancel()
        
    }()
    buf1, err := read(ctx1, os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    ctx2, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*2)
    buf2, err := read(ctx2, os.Stdin)

    fmt.Println("buf1")
    fmt.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(buf1))
    fmt.Println("buf2")
    fmt.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(buf2))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go on and explore the simplicity offer by go
https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel

You can have a `context` that returning `CancelFunc` then you use `context.WithCancel`.
And execute `cancel` func if you want to terminate.

This is the good practice way, you can also do a dirty `os.Exit(0)` in another case.